# What is the ARGB format required by the ImageService in Google App Engine (java)

Tags: java, image, google-app-engine, hex

For some reason, the [Google API expects longs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/images/ImagesService#composite%28java.util.Collection,%20int,%20int,%20long%29) instead of objects (like Color). What is the format for this and how can I pass it in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just define this in hex directly in the call. Each pair represents Alpha (transparency), Red, Green and Blue:

eg: 0xFF00FF00 is solid green

Define your long by placing "L" after the hex:

```
    Image i = imageService.composite(images, 100, 100, 0xff00ff00L);
```